# Translating English to Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there is a student in this class who has chatted with exactly one other student

$$ \exists x\exists y(y\ne x\land \forall z(z\ne x\to(z=y\leftrightarrow C(x,z))))$$
ƎxƎy(y ≠ x ^ ∀(z ≠ x -> ( z= <->C(x,z)))).    ( answer)

Can someone explain the answer to me? Ive been stumped on this for a while.

Comment: I rewote the formula in TeX and at the same time inserted a few letters needed to make sense of it in the first place. Please check with your given text that my additions are correct.

Comment: It is correct. Thank you.